# Why are numeric values in attribute table not sorted correctly?

Tags: qgis, sorting

I have a problem with the new QGIS version (2.16.0 or 2.16.1 Nodebo). I want to sort numeric values in the attribute table by clicking on the field name. But in contrast to older QGIs versions the attributes are not sorted correctly. It feels like QGIS recognizes it as text. but in the layer properties under fields it says the attributes are numeric (double or integer).

Comment: What is the expected sort order and how is it currently sorted?

Comment: I suppose that list "1, 2, 10" gets sorted as " 1, 10, 2". It seems to be noticed by others as well http://osdir.com/ml/qgis-user-gis/2016-08/msg00106.html. Perhaps side effect of fixing another sorting fix https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14927.

Comment: exactly, it sorts 1,10,2. okay, I am looking forward to version 2.16.2 ;) thanks for the comments

Comment: I have the same problem with QGIS 2.18-2 (OSX environment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in QGIS 2.16.0 and 2.16.1 and has been reported [in the bug tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15295).

It has been resolved and 2.16.2 will no longer suffer from this problem.

> As usual, you can install a nightly (in this case `qgis-rel-dev`) to get a fixed version before the next point release. Installing nightly versions is not only good to get fixes early on. It also helps to verify that the problems are really fixed. In case problems persist (or new problems have been introduced) these can be assessed before the next point release.