# How to sort field by ascending numerical order in QGIS 2.14?

Tags: symbology, fields-attributes, qgis-2.14, sorting

I work with this field (in categorized style):

[image]

I try to find how can I sort the "value" column (in the style properties) by ascending numerical order. In the attribute table "value" is "YEUD" field:

[image]

"YEUD" field id numerical field:

[image]

The problem is when I click on "value" name, it sorts the field not the way I am seeking.

I read [Why are numeric values in attribute table not sorted correctly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207100/why-are-numeric-values-in-attribute-table-not-sorted-correctly) and my version is earlier,  and also I don't want to update my QGIS version.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the datatype of the "value" field. If it is a character type, then the sort order is correct. You can change the datatype or alter the format to sort in numerical order.

Comment: I tried in QGIS 2.14.3 a categorized thematic map on an integer field. Clicking on the header of value I got correct numeric order, clicking on legend column I got non-numeric sort (1,10,11, ..., 2). In the layer panel I got the last order set in style dialog.

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. As original poster (OP), your job is to edit the question to be a clear and as detailed as possible. Specifying that it is the layer panel you want sorted is critical. Given the realities of software development, refusing to use a newer release to attain a necessary bug fix seems counterproductive.

Comment: i edited my question now

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug that has been fixed.

You can either update your QGIS LTR version, or sort the values manually.

Click and drag any row and place it in any order, like you would rearrange the layer order.

[image]