# Sorting error QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I'am on QGIS 2.18-2 OSX version.

I have a communal table with integer fiels for population and jobs.

In the attribute table I would like so sort communal population by size order. But I got wrong result. Any idea why that happened?

See attached screen. [image: Wrong sorting]

Here some people said that problem was solved on older version but, no I still got this : [Why are numeric values in attribute table not sorted correctly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207100/why-are-numeric-values-in-attribute-table-not-sorted-correctly)

Comment: Are you sure that population is numeric type and not string or text ?